# How to animate independent mesh parts

Tags: animation, unity

I have kind of floor cell made of pieces

[image: http://prntscr.com/c66m4m]

I want to animate it so it can fall into pieces.

Do I need to create an armature for it? Or there is a possibility to animate parts of mesh without bones?

I need this animation to be supported by unity.

**Update:** I think I have an idea how to proceed here. I did a separation into parts as was proposed. But instead adding a physics I can animate these parts manually. Without bones, just save positions of each piece into keyframes. Is it good idea?

Comment: In the future please add the image using links to this site. External links might disappear or expire and then your question will make no sense.

Comment: Looks like you what to separate by loose parts, add physics to each part, and then bake the physics keyframes.  Or if you wanted to animate by hand, press "i," move forward a couple frames, move the object, press "i," repeat.  For games, you may want to increase the frame rate in Blender to 60 for 1 to 1 animation.

Comment: @Gliderman, do you have any links to tutorials on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution proposed by @Gliderman helped. I did a split into separate objects and animated them separately. I put location and rotation values into keyframes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try Animation Nodes if you are going for some sort of procedural animation. It gives you the ability to create parametric animations, like ICE in SoftImage or Xpresso in C4D

https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes